What is the usage of で here?

"社長の息子で顔も頭もよくて女に不自由したことはない勝ち組" 周囲の俺への評価はこんな感じ.-----ぶっちゃけ異論はない.

My attempt to understand:

The company presidents son, has a good face, smart, doesn't have any problems getting girls and is winning in life" Is probably what everyone around me assumed of me. And to be honest, I don't disagree with them.

What exactly is the usage of で here? Another example sentence could help as well. Also, is the の just adding emphasis on the fact that he assumed people think that of him?


The で in bold is simply the te-form of だ. It's the same で as in "今日は月曜日で明日は火曜日だ". Grammatically, this で is a form of a copula, not a particle.
The の in bold is not adding any emphasis; it is necessary for the sentence to be grammatical. 俺への評価 means "evaluation of me", while 俺へ評価 makes no sense by itself. See: using の with と,で, から, まで

